# Am I right in thinking this snippet is O(n^3)?

Tags: c#, big-o

```
collection.Where(i => i.condition)
.ToList()
.ForEach(i => SomeComplicatedOpInvolving_i);
```

I'm not looking for answers telling me there is an easier way of doing this, just treat it as a thought experiment.

First up, am I right in thinking that this is three loops? `Where()`, `ToList()` and `ForEach()`?
Second of all, (assuming it is three loops) am I right in thinking this is n to the power of 3 in big O notation?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Does it not depend on what SomeComplicatedOpInvolving_i does?

Comment: If we assume that `collection` is of type `IEnumerable<T>`, then it will only be O(2*n), due to lazy loading.

Comment: Don't `ToList` just because you don't want to use a normal `foreach()` loop, since creating and filling the list is by far the most intensive operation in this snippet.

Comment: @Dykam Yes, it was the introduction of the ToList() that led me to investigate this algo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, actually. I think it should be O(n).

`Where()` runs in O(n) (assuming `condition` is constant)

`ToList()` runs over all the results of `Where` as well, so O(n) too

`ForEach()` runs over the entire list produced by `ToList` once, so also O(n). I assume `SomeComplicatedOpInvolving_i` doesn't scale with the number of i's...

The key point here is that the loops aren't nested, they run one after another - so total runtime is 3*O(n), which is the same as O(n).

Comment: +1 for taking into account the complexity of subexpressions and stating clearly that one can write the complexity involving a 3 but it's doesn't matter.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, ToList isn't O(n), because sometimes it has to copy to grow :-)

Comment: Precisely the explanation I was looking for thank you for taking the time to break it down. It was the 3*n vs n^3 that I was mixed up by.

Comment: xanatos: The documentation for ToList() doesn't specify performance directly, but the constructor of List says it runs in O(n).

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not nested loops.  It is O(n).

Avoid using ToList(), that costs O(n) storage for no good reason.  Check this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's `O(n)`. It would only be `O(n^3)` if there was a loop within a loop within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is `O(n)`.

As `Where` is `O(n)` this means that the cost of `Where` is approximately `A x n`, for some `A`.

Similarly as `ToList` and `ForEach` are also `O(n)` which means their cost is approximately `B x n` and `C x n` respective, for some `B` and some `C`.

This means that the total cost is roughly:

```
  (A x n) + (B x n) + (C x n)
= (A + B + C) x n 
= D x n
```

For some `D` (we never really cared what `A`, `B` and `C` were, so we also don't care what `A + B + C` is, so just call it `D` to make our equation simpler).

Hence this operation is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.Where(i => i.condition) // is O(n) where n is the size of collection
.ToList() // is O(m) where m is the number if items with i.condition true
.ForEach(i => SomeComplicatedOpInvolving_i);  // O(m) where m is the number if items with i.condition true
```

Assuming that SomeComplicatedOpInvolving is O(1), e.g. it does not make longer if you have more items.

Given that

```
when m is never bigger then n, then 
O(n) + O(m) + O(m) == O(n)
```

Then the snippet is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

It's O(collection.Size) * O(SomeComplicatedOpInvolving_i).